# Можно ли сделать тень вокруг треугольника с помощью стилей?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть блок со треугольником-указателем снизу и обводкой тени вокруг. Вопрос: можно ли как-то с помощью стилей сделать тень вокруг треугольника, а не прозрачной подложке на которой он лежит или это не возможно? [Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/Lh808gk4/)

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -13px;
  left: 35px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 13px 15.5px 0 15.5px;
  border-color: yellow transparent transparent transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsbnat05/1/)

```css
div {
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
div:after,
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -12px;
  background: yellow;
  margin-left: -12px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
div:before {
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Более подробно - [Треугольники через CSS](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/treugolniki-cherez-css)

Answer (score 9):

Так, чтоб это смотрелось целостно при любой тени и произвольном треугольнике - возможно, что нет. Но примерно, попробовать можно так:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
div:after {
  content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;       
    bottom: -2em;
    left: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;        
    border: 1em solid black;
    border-color: transparent transparent yellow yellow;
    
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);        
    box-shadow: -3px 3px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

  /*
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -13px;
  left: 35px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 13px 15.5px 0 15.5px;
  border-color: yellow transparent transparent transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: хороший способ, но треугольник стал каким-то огроменным! я вот что подумал - что если сделать ромб и подложить его под блок?

Comment: @Вася честно говоря не знаю. Ведь блок тогда будет обнесен весь тенью. Стоит подождать пока кто еще ответит, может кто подскажет что хорошее

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko я вот как раз о вас думал! :)

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko У вас хороший опыт в верстке и css. Было бы интересно увидеть  хороший правильный ответ от профессионала, а не от дилетанта вроде меня

Answer (score 7):

Есть с ромбиками, добавлю еще с треугольниками и размытием:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

div:after,
div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px; 
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15.5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15.5px solid transparent;
}

div:after { 
  z-index: 3;
  bottom: -13px;     
  border-top: 13px solid yellow;
}

div:before {
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: -15px; 
    border-top: 13px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

P.S: У soledar10 правильнее решение!